# Finding similarities between two columns in two datasets in Python: optimization of approach

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine i have the following datasets:

```
import difflib as dl
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,'one'],[2,'two'],[3,'three'],[4,'four'],[5,'five'],[7,'seven']], columns=['number', 'name'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,'one'],[2,'two'],[3,'three'],[4,'four'],[5,'five'],[55,'five'],[555,'five'],[6,'six'],[7,'seven'],[77,'seven'],[777,'seven'],[8,'eight']], columns=['number', 'name'])
```

I want to find similarities between name columns of the two datasets and for this i use `difflib` library and `apply` method from pandas:

```
df1['duplicates'] = df1['name'].apply(lambda x: dl.get_close_matches(x, df2['name'], cutoff=0.75, n=5))
```

after this i use `explode`, in order to expand lists into separate records:

```
df1 = df1.explode('duplicates').reset_index(drop=True).drop_duplicates(subset=['duplicates'],keep="last")
df1.reset_index(drop=True,inplace = True)
```

At the end I got the following result:

```
  number  name    duplicates
0   1     one      one
1   2     two      two
2   3     three    three
3   4     four     four
4   5     five     five
5   7     seven    seven
```

But in the final dataframe I want to get duplicate ID's as well(from df_2).

Of course, i can use `pd.merge` function, but for big datasets(10k records) it's slow and I suppose, there is a better approach for achieving my goal.

Can we return duplicate id's in `apply` function?
Is there better approach than 'pd.merge'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure exactly what output you are expecting but you can use `.isin()` method [see pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)

This would be a lot faster than doing a merge.

So something like

```py
duplicates = df2[df2['name'].isin(df1['name'])]
```

This outputs the following, which gives you the IDs from df2, where the name is duplicated in df1.

|  | number | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | one |
| 1 | 2 | two |
| 2 | 3 | three |
| 3 | 4 | four |
| 4 | 5 | five |
| 5 | 55 | five |
| 6 | 555 | five |
| 7 | 6 | six |
| 8 | 7 | seven |
| 9 | 77 | seven |
| 10 | 777 | seven |